# Bash script for finding number of files, directories, and temporary files in a directory

Tags: bash, scripts

I want to write a shell script that counts number of files, directories, and temporary files in a directory. The script below throws an error.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd '/home/Ubuntulover/Shell'

file=0
dir=0
temp=0
for d in *;
do
 for f in *;
 do
    if [ -d "$d" ]; then
        dir=$((dir+1))
    elif [ -f "$f" ]; then
        file=$((file+1))
    else
        temp=$((temp+1))
    fi
done
echo "Files $file"
echo "Directories $dir"
echo "Temporaryfiles $temp"
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Answer (score 2):

You have syntax error as `done` keyword is missing in upper most `for` loop:

```
 #!/bin/bash

cd '/home/479153/Temp' || exit

file=0
dir=0
temp=0
for d in *;
do
    for f in *; # this loop actually not needed
     do
        if [ -d "$d" ]; then
            dir=$((dir+1))
        elif [ -f "$f" ]; then # can be replace as $d
            file=$((file+1))
        else
            temp=$((temp+1))
        fi
    done
done
echo "Files $file"
echo "Directories $dir"
echo "Temporaryfiles $temp"
```

You can always use http://www.shellcheck.net/ site to check syntax error in your bash code.

Comment: This fixes the syntax, but without making it actually work correctly as the real bug is the extra `for` not the missing `done`!

Comment: True. This program can be reduce to generate same output.

Comment: No, it doesn't - see my answer below.

Comment: Please see my comments in program.

Answer (score 2):

You have too many `for` statements: As it stands, there is a loop variable d counting through all items in a directory, and a second loop variable f doing this again for each file present - so if you have 4 files then you will get 4*4=16 iterations (or would if the `done`'s were correct).

You could use a statement like `ls -l | wc -l` to do a quick check that the ball-park figure is OK.

I reckon this is more what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd '/home/Ubuntulover/Shell'

file=0
dir=0
temp=0
for d in *;
do
  if [ -d "$d" ]; then
    dir=$((dir+1))
  elif [ -f "$d" ]; then
    file=$((file+1))
  else
    temp=$((temp+1))
  fi
done
echo "Files $file"
echo "Directories $dir"
echo "Temporaryfiles $temp"
```